# Generate Prisma schema from typescript interfaces

Tags: typescript, mongodb, prisma

I'm moving from a custom DB to MongoDB, and using Prisma as an ORM.

I have all my tables defined as typescript interfaces and would like to know if it's possible to generate a Prisma schema from typescript interfaces.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, from which database are you migrating? Does that database support introspection? If yes, you can introspect the database to generate the schema file by reading tables from your database. https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/introspection

Comment: @NurulSundarani It’s a custom DB, kind of half SQL half MongoDB, so I can’t use introspection, but I do have the models as typescript interfaces.